# Use a value from a column to call a function (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

**I am trying to call a function that uses as a second parameter the value of the first column of this Select in the Where clause** (... = table_timescode.code). But it is not working for me.

This is what I am trying:

```
    Select code, name, 
    [stored_proced] ('3',(Select Min(bol.line) as Line From table_bone bon join table_line bol on 
       bon.code = bol.code where bon.code = table_timescode.code),1) as SuperCode           
    From table_timescode
    Where (Day >= convert(datetime, '18/05/2020', 103));
```

I am using *Transact-SQL* in *Microsoft SQL Server*.

Comment: Check cross\outer apply and also TVF's.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

You cannot use a stored procedure in a SQL query.  That is by definition.  Three options come to mind:

1. Convert the stored procedure to a stored function.
2. Save the results of the stored procedure in a table.
3. Move the logic of the stored procedure directly into the query or perhaps into a view.

The second option is rather cumbersome, because you are using a correlated subquery.  So it is not going to work, unless you replace your code with a loop (and using -- horror of horrors -- a cursor).

The first or third options are the best method.  Note that not all stored procedures can be turned into functions, so it might not be possible.

Comment: Sorry Gordon, is a function what I am using.